# How to access Visibility property of the ListBoxItems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listboxitem

In my WPF program I have a `ListBox` control:

```
<ListBox x:Name="mailsListBox" SelectionChanged="mailsListBox_SelectionChanged" >
    <ListBoxItem Content="..." Background="#FFF3F3F3" Margin="0,0,0,1" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="...." Margin="0,0,0,1" Visibility="Hidden"/>
</ListBox>
```

How can I access `Visibility` property of the `ListBoxItems`? My code doesn't works:

```
mailsListBox.Items[1].Visibility = Visible;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
(mailsListBox.Items[1] as ListBoxItem).Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Or you can use [`ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromitem(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
((ListBoxItem)(mailsListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(mailsListBox.Items[1]))).Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```