# Get selected ListViewItem container from ListView in Windows Universal App

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Is there a way to get the `ListViewItem` container when a `ListView`s selection has changed. I've tried using

```
listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listView.SelectedItem);
```

from the `ListView`s selection changed event but this always returns null. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access Visibility property of the ListBoxItems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553035/how-to-access-visibility-property-of-the-listboxitems)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind RowItems}"
              SelectionChanged="ListView_OnSelectionChanged"/>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void ListView_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.AddedItems?.FirstOrDefault();
    // edit: also get container
    var container = ((ListViewItem) (listView.ContainerFromItem(item)));
}
```

Note that `listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem` is obsolete since Windows 8.1.

Comment: Those give me the object in the array that the listview is bound to not the ListViewItem container

Comment: It was not completely clear to my you only wanted the container, I added it to the question and my reply.

Comment: It works, apart from when the menu first appears. Then container is null. Every other time it works though