# ListView Container in UWP

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

I am trying to get the container of the currently selected ListView item. ContainerFromItem returns always null and the compiler complains that the function may be obsolete.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Also take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553035/how-to-access-visibility-property-of-the-listboxitems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ContainerFromItem returns always null.

[ItemsControl.ContainerFromItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.containerfromitem) method can get the container for the specified item. For example, we can get a [ListViewItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewitem.aspx) container from the selected item in a `ListView`. If you got null, maybe the item doesn't have a container exists or something wrong with your code.

> I am trying to get the container of the currently selected ListView item.

Here is a complete demo for getting the container of the currenttly selected `ListViewItem`.
XAML code:

```
<ListView
    Name="CListView"
    Margin="10"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"         
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind categories}"
    SelectionChanged="CListView_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Category">
            <StackPanel             
                Background="{x:Bind backgroundcolor}"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock                           
                    FontSize="17"
                    FontWeight="Bold"
                    Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code behind

```
  ObservableCollection<Category> categories = new ObservableCollection<Category> { };
  public ListViewContainer()
  {
      this.InitializeComponent();
      categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>
      {
          new Category {Name="name1",details="color1" ,backgroundcolor="#D90015"},
          new Category {Name="name2",details="color2" ,backgroundcolor="#DC1C17"},
          new Category {Name="name3",details="cplor3",backgroundcolor="#DE3A17" },
          new Category {Name="name3",details="color4",backgroundcolor="#E25819" }
      };
  } 
  private void CListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      var  container = CListView.ContainerFromItem(CListView.SelectedItem);
      ListViewItem item = container as ListViewItem;
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.ActualHeight);
  }
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you.