# Get content of selected ListViewItem from ListView bound to a Model

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a `ListView` who's source is bound to an `ObservableCollection<MyModel>`. When I select an item, using single item mode, I'd like to access the content of the selected item's xaml. I'd like to access the `TextBox` of the selected item and modify it in my code. I'm sure I could use visual states to do this.

But my problem is, the returned selected item is an instance of `MyModel` and I can't see an obvious way to get the content of the selected item. Even if I traverse `Items` property of the `ListView` I get an array of `MyModel` with no obvious way to access the `TextBox` for the returned selected item.

Any ideas and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What about `ContainerFromItem` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553035/how-to-access-visibility-property-of-the-listboxitems

Comment: @S.Akbari thank you for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a method that maps the model/value to the actual UI container:

```
ListView listView;
MyModel model;

var uiElement = listView.ContainerFromItem(model);
```

You can also get it by index:

```
var uiElement = listView.ContainerFromIndex(5);
```

Comment: Thank you Laith, that was helpful. And much easier than creating a `UserControl` and invoking some logic there from the selection changed callback.